# Error configuring large page support on Centos 7 VPS

Tags: centos, memory, vps, huge-pages

I am trying to mine Monero with my VPS, but I encountered an error when trying to enable large pages support. The miner I am trying to use is XMR STAK CPU, but I do not believe this to be the issue, although when I run it, it says "MEMORY ALLOC FAILED: mmap failed".

I am running Centos 7 and I complied the miner myself. I tried doing what it says to do in the README, but the command fails even when executing as root.

```
$ sudo sysctl -w vm.nr_hugepages=128
sysctl: permission denied on key 'vm.nr_hugepages'
```

I also added these lines to /etc/security/limits.conf

```
* soft memlock 262144
* hard memlock 262144
```

Even running the miner as root doesn't solve my problem.

Additional resources

Here is my strace output: https://pastebin.com/W3QJ8jne

Here is my syslog: https://pastebin.com/drt3Nhcv

SELinux is set to permissive mode as well.

dmesg doesn't output anything...

Answer (score 0):

With respect to `sudo sysctl -w vm.nr_hugepages=128`, I know some settings available in sysctl are not modifiable after boot, I don't know if this is one of them or not.

I recommend adding `vm.nr_hugepages = 128` to your `/etc/sysctl.conf` file and rebooting.